# GeoJSON EPSG::25833 TO WGS 84/MAPBOX PROJECTion

Tags: geojson

I have this GeoJSON file that is

```
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" } },
```

I want to display this in Mapbox but that dosent work since it it is 25833 and it keeps giving me error. How can I make this into a WGS 84 or EPSG:3857 as Mapbox is using from what I can tell?
Should be said that is is MultiPolygon geometry

Comment: Reproject to default GeoJSON projection with for example ogr2ogr. Usage: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs epsg:4326 output.json input.json`.

Comment: @user30184 Found https://mapshaper.org/ and managed to convert, but do you think the conversion is equally accurate?

Comment: I guess so but feel free to test.

Comment: If MapBox is honouring the GeoJSON specification, then it is expecting is CRS:84, not EPSG:3857 or EPSG:4326